# 500 Error After Moving Code To New Server

Tags: php, tinybutstrong

I recently moved my code to a new server with Debian 10 and PHP 7.3.19. The old server had Ubuntu 16.04.15 and PHP 7.0.33. As a result, I am now getting a 500 error on my index.php page. However, if I comment out part of the TinyButStrong template code, the error goes away and loads. Below is a snippet of the code and the commented out section.

```
$tbs_source = ($DBConn===false) ? 'clear' : $DBConn;
// Merge data and close connection
$TBS->MergeBlock('songblock', $tbs_source, $sql);

/*$TBS->MergeBlock('titleblock', $tbs_source,
'SELECT t.*, stt.sortID FROM titles t 
        INNER JOIN songlist_titles_tunes stt ON t.ID = stt.titlesID 
        WHERE stt.songlistID = %p1% GROUP BY t.ID ORDER BY stt.sortID');
$TBS->MergeBlock('tuneblock', $tbs_source,
'SELECT tunes.*, stt.sortID FROM tunes 
        INNER JOIN songlist_titles_tunes stt ON tunes.id = stt.tunesID
        WHERE songlistID = %p1% AND titlesID = %p2% ORDER BY stt.sortID'); // */

$DBConn = null; // this is the method to close PDO connection
```

The version of TBS is:

```
 * TinyButStrong - Template Engine for Pro and Beginners
 *
 * @version 3.11.0 for PHP 5 and 7
 * @date    2019-02-10
```

Any thoughts on why just that section is raising a 500 error?

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: Thanks. The error log helped reveal a SQL error that is causing the 500 error. The MySQL version is newer and only_full_group_by is causing an issue on the MySQL call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your htaccess file. Maybe some features of your old server is not enabled in your new server. Also check the file's permission. chmod it to 755.

Comment: @aynber pointed me in the right direction where I have found what is the problem.